# Making random phone number

Tags: python

I want to create phone number generator with the following restrictions:

- start with 0.
- Second number must be 1.
- Third number can be on these 2,3,5.
- Number is 11 digits.
- Don't want the same number twice.

This is the code I used:

```
# import module import random as r

ph_no = []
ph_no2 = []

# the first number should be in the range of 6 to 9
ph_no.append(r.randint(0, 1))

ph_no2.append(r.randint(1, ))
# the for loop is used to append the other 9 numbers.
# the other 9 numbers can be in the range of 0 to 9.
for i in range(1, 10):
    ph_no.append(r.randint(0, 9))
    ph_no2.append(r.randint(0,9))

# printing the number
for i in ph_no:
    print(i, end="")
```

This is the problem:

```
ph_no2.append(r.randint(1, ))
TypeError: Random.randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 
'b'
```

I want help to make this code work.

Edite:

I used this code to print the output into a txt file but it doesn't print all the output:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "w") as external_file:
    add_text = "This text will be added to the file"
    print(pn(), file=external_file)
    external_file.close()
```

Comment: It appears as though you’ve forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Explain your problem, what is working, what isn't ? And you can use `"".join(ph_no)` to print the phone number instead of using a for loop

Comment: randint return a random int between the given range, `1,`  isn't a range, you have to give the second boundary. Looks like you forgot to add 0 at the beginning

Comment: randint() takes two arguments, the start and stop and returns a random integer in the range (start and stop inclusive). Read
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: I want the first number be Only 0 and the second number be only one

Comment: If the second number has to be 1, why not append 1 then instead of using the randint function?

Comment: Can you explain more pls?

Comment: How can the number be 11 digits and you don't want the same number twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) has an argument for start and stop. You're missing one

```py
# 0 is start, 10 is stop
>>> r.randint(0,10)
6
```

Use `ph_no2.append(r.randint(start, stop))`

---

Here's a phone number generator with your requirements:

```py
import random as r


def pn():

    # start with 0.
    # Second number must be 1.
    number = '01'

    # Third number can be on these 2,3,5.
    number += r.choice('235')

    # Number is 11 digits.
    for i in range(8):
        number += r.choice('0123456789')

    return number
```

```
>>> pn()
'01523693965'
```

---

**Edit**:

To get `n` numbers, and none are the same

```
# Set does not have duplicates
all_numbers = set()
n = 10

while len(all_numbers) < n:
    # Continue adding until you have `n` numbers
    x = pn()
    print(x)
    all_numbers.add(x)
```

```
01561915353
01558729923
01512093981
01589320526
...
```

> [`set` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: why using random.choice instead of random.randint ?

Comment: OP says they do not want to repeat number `Don't want the same number twice.`

Comment: @TalhaTayyab, how do they get numbers 0-9 11 times without repeating?

Comment: Thats work but what is i want to print 10 numbers had I repeat It 10 times?

Comment: @MariusROBERT, because I would just cast it back to a string anyway. `choice` picks me a string

Comment: @Moaz if you want 10 phone numbers, made a for loop and print/save them

Comment: @Moaz, added. see edit

Comment: if the number is already in the set it won't add it, resulting in only 9 numbers instead of 10. This code produces at most 10 numbers (and only 1 if you are extremely unlucky)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki good point - fixed

Answer (score 1):

This uses [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)'s [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) and [`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random


def random_number():
    number = list(
        str(random.randint(11111111111, 99999999999))
    )  # 11 random digits to str
    number[0] = '0'  # start with 0
    number[1] = '1'  # second number must be 1
    number[2] = str(random.choice([2, 3, 5]))  # third number can be 2, 3, or 5

    return ''.join(number)
```

Usage: `random_number()` returns a random number

```py
for i in range(0, 9):
    print(random_number())
```

Output example:

```
01247829529
01389527108
01513481001
01284462585
01305116767
01219669837
01239182461
01245292538
01284163077
```

Explanation: Works by casting `int` -> `str` -> `list` -> editing the individual numbers in place -> rejoining to a single `str` -> `int()`

Comment: still, the second number is not 1.

Comment: it should to be like number[1] = 1 , the return also will be str(''.join(number))

Comment: Good catches @SubhamSubhasisPatra! Fixed. Better if you try now?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random as r
for x in range(10):
  ph_no = [0,1]   # first 2 numbers
  ph_no.append(*r.sample([2,3,5],1))  # Third number

  #remaining numbers
  while len(ph_no)<11:
    k=r.randint(0, 9)
    if k not in ph_no[1:]: # we are skipping zero as we cannot have 11 unique numbers from 0-9
      ph_no.append(k)
    else:
      continue
  print(''.join(str(x) for x in ph_no))

#output
01327486095
01508746239
01567293084
01346857920
01520693874
01369405827
01384290657
01563082479
01520947386
01532460879
```